# What options are there for ADB2C authentication flows which do not use JavaScript?

Tags: authentication, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We've created a website which uses ADB2C for authentication. We've used custom policies to define auth flows such as SignUpSignIn, PasswordReset etc.

We need to support the use case where a user might not have JavaScript enabled. I see that some identity providers do this (Facebook, Amazon).

What options are there for providing **no-js authentication flows using ADB2C?**

We've been looking at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdCWYlEc41s), which makes use of some logic in the web application, a self issued JWT and some clever custom policies and technical profiles. It looks promising. Are there any other ways to achieve a no-js authentication experience with ADB2C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a site that provides pages to B2C using OpenID Connect.

Instead of B2C showing a self asserted page it would redirect to your site using OpenID Connect, your site would show the UI and then return a token to B2C containing the captured data, B2C would then use that data and produce its own token back to the relying party.

As far as I know there's currently no way to run a B2C self asserted page without JavaScript due to the way the page loads its content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think without JavaScript enabled in browser, user flow or custom policy will work. If JavaScript is disabled, then may using [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-aad-b2c-considerations#resource-owner-password-credentials-ropc) flow will help you to achieve the use cases, but before choosing **ROPC** please read the article and make a decision. ROPC work only with **Local accounts**